# JQuery onclick link inside a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Hi I have a link inside a `<ul>` tag I am trying to get the click event of all `<a>` tag inside the `pagination` class. This the code

```
<ul class='pagination'>
<li class='details'>Page 1 of 2</li>
<li><a class='current'>1</a></li>
<li><a href='?page=2'>2</a></li>
<li><a href='?page=2'>Next</a></li>
<li><a href='?page=2'>Last</a></li>
</ul>
```

what I tried is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("a.pagination").click(function(){alert("something..")})
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The selector you used will get achor `a` with class `pagination`, use [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) like this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QttKr/)**

```
$(".pagination a").click(function(){alert("something..")})
```

Answer (score 2):

To exclude ".current"...

```
$(".pagination a[href]").click(function(){ alert("something..")}) });
```

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting `a.pagination` which is wrong.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("ul.pagination a").click(function(){alert("something..")}) });
```